# Two menu items in the top bar redirect to the same page

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, help-center, stackoverflow.co

The "About Us" and "Business" options in the "Help Center and other resources" menu from the top bar of all the sites are redirecting to the same page: https://stackoverflow.co

Previously those options were linked to https://stackoverflow.com/company and https://stackoverflowbusiness.com pages. But due to this change [New official secondary domain: stackoverflow.co](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415962/2451726), now both URLs point to the same page.

Please decide whether the "About Us" and "Business" options should be combined or both should point to their respective pages.

[image: "Help Center and other resources" menu options and the last two options 'About' and 'Business' are circled]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. The "Business" link has been removed, with the language under "About us" being slightly adjusted.

---

> duplicate menu
> links to company pages…
> redundancy gone

Comment: Semi-related: [Inconsistent punctuation in the '?' dropdown menu in the top-bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388294/335251)