# Inconsistent punctuation in the '?' dropdown menu in the top-bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, grammar

In the top-bar, clicking on the '?' button (not sure what it's called), opens a dropdown menu for 'Tour,' 'Help Center,' 'Meta,' and 'About Us.' (Meta sites are slightly different, but the issue is there, too.)

It looks like this:

[image]

The text under the first three sections doesn't have end punctuation, but the 'About Us' section does have a period at the end, after 'products'. This is inconsistent with the others (and with the description for 'What's Meta' that shows up on Metas).

This doesn't seem to have always been the case; when searching for duplicates, I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386351/two-menu-items-in-the-top-bar-redirect-to-the-same-page) question from two months ago in which a [screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386351/two-menu-items-in-the-top-bar-redirect-to-the-same-page) shows consistent punctuation.

It's a bit trivial, but can the period in the description for 'About Us' be removed so that all of these are consistently punctuated?

Comment: This is not about a spelling error.

Comment: @Mari-LouA but it is about grammar.

Comment: @Shadow It's not even about grammar. How would you spell the word "error" aloud? Would you include punctuation marks? In speech no punctuation is needed; it is all about writing. For instance, punctuation clarifies whether a new sentence has began, or if a sentence is a question. We do this naturally in speech all the time by adding pauses, modifying the tone, or inverting an auxiliary with the subject. Grammar is something completely different, it includes both speech and writing. If I say "**Like you say "error"?**“ that would be ungrammatical even though the punctuation would be correct!

Comment: @Mari-Lou well, feel free to start a meta discussion asking if a new tag is fitting for punctuation (or try yourself, but others might roll it back), and until then, grammar is the closest thing we have, even if not 100% strictly correct. I do agree spelling isn't fitting for punctuation bugs.

Answer (score 9):

I put in a pull request to fix this :) I should be able to get it merged in after Jan 1st, 2024.

This has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in January 2<sup>nd</sup>, 2024.